# What happen when you cast from an abstract to an interface?

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism, abstract

Can anyone explain what really happen behind the scene when you cast from an **abstract/Interface** to an interface?

Example: Let say `AbstractClasse a = new Concrete()` and `Concrete` implements both `IText` interface and `AbstractClasse` and we say `IText = (IText)a`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        interface IText
        {
            string ToText();
        }
        class Subtip : SubtitleFormat, IText
        {
            public int Error { get; set; }

            public Subtip(int error)
            {
                Error = error;
            }
            public string ToText()
            {
                return $"{Error}, Hello!";
            }
        }
        abstract class SubtitleFormat
        {
            protected int _errorCount = 1;

            public int ErrorCount
            {
                get
                {
                    return _errorCount;
                }
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SubtitleFormat sb = new Subtip(10);
            IText sb2 = sb as IText;

            Console.WriteLine(sb.ErrorCount);
            Console.WriteLine((sb as Subtip).Error);
            Console.WriteLine(sb2.ToText());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well for starters the `as` keyword is not the same as a cast, a cast will throw an exception if the cast isn't possible and is generally slower. To answer your question though the `as` keyword generates as isinst IL instruction which causes the VM to call a routine that traverses the class type's inheritance list as well as a separate array the VM creates which contains all the interfaces that the class implements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value of a class type can be converted to type object or to an interface type that is implemented by the class simply by treating the reference as another type at compile-time. Likewise, a value of type object or a value of an interface type can be converted back to a class type without changing the reference (but of course a run-time type check is required in this case).

**Source**: *CSharp Language Specification*

Answer (score 1):

When you cast to an interface or class the proper type of the object in question is used to determine whether it is compatible with the target.  It is largely irrelevant what the object is currently typed to - `object`, `interface`, final `class` or base `class`.

So, for instance, you can do this:

```
SubtitleFormat sb = new Subtip(10);
IText sb2 = sb as IText;
Subtip sb3 = sb2 as Subtip;
```

Both of those conversions are valid, so at the end of it `sb3` will have a non-null value.  All three variables (`sb`, `sb2` and `sb3`) will refer to the same object, so `Object.ReferenceEquals(sb, sb3)` will be true.

Because the true type of the object instance is used to determine whether or not the cast will work, something like this *won't* work:

```
public class NotIText : SubtitleFormat
{
    public string ToText()
    {
        return "";
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SubtitleFormat sb = new NotIText();
    IText sb2 = sb as IText;
}
```